# Best way to track down dependencies? (Wordpress + Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am wondering what the best ways are to track down dependencies (I think that is the best way to describe it) between several files. Here are the details.

Context: I am working on adding a plugin called WooCommerce Product Bundles to the online store that I am managing. The plugin takes several products and combines them onto one page with a short description for each product.

The Problem: When the plugin is pulling in the short description for each product it is also pulling in the contents of **product-elements.php** which has a "Find a Dealer" button inside of it. This big button is then repeated 4 times on the rendered page and looks terrible.

The Goal: Is to remove these buttons by removing the hook for "product-elements.php" from the plugin, since nothing in that file needs to be displayed on the rendered page.

However... I cannot for the life of me find any references to **product-elements.php** in the plugin files... which means it is probably referencing another product page template file, which is then referencing something else, which is then referencing "product-elements.php".
If you guys understand what I am saying here... what is the best way to trace the full path of these files so I can find the actual reference I am looking for (and kill it with fire)?

Additional details:
- **product-elements.php** is a file in my theme. It is a default Woocommerce file that has been copied over and modified (sort of like a child theme, but it is a child file).
- Something in the bundle plugin files is pulling **product-elements.php** into the rendered page, but it is not referenced directly.
- There has to be some middle step in between these directories where there is a trail of references, how do I find it?
- Tools I am using, OSX, Tower(GIT), Atom text editor

Comment: On another thread I found a suggestion that in Atom you can use CMD+SHFT+F to "Search in Project". This search function may not be working correctly though...

Comment: google developer console -> resources (albeit doesn't always provide full path)